# Spring MVC + Spring Security Component Scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have encountered a problem where the mappings are getting initialized twice.

Here is my **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.beo")
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/Resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/Resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public ExcelBuilder excelbuilder() {
    return new ExcelBuilder();
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver setupViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    InternalResourceViewResolver InternalResourceResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    InternalResourceResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    InternalResourceResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolvers.add(InternalResourceResolver);

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver2 = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver2.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    resolver2.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    return resolver2;

}
}
```

As you can see I have annotated it with a **@Componentscan**.

Now Here is My **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.beo")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("security scan");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated().antMatchers("/sec/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/panel").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable().and()
            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
            passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

I am forced to annotate the **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** with another **@ComponentScan** because if I don't, I will be getting an error regarding the autowiring of **UserDetailsService**.

But with this configuration, all my mappings are being initialized twice.
Any ideas on how to fix this? :(

**UPDATE**

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ActiveUser loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserAccounts user = userDao.findByEmail(email);
        if (user != null) {
            // String password = user.getPassword();

            // additional security object information
            boolean enabled = user.getStatus().equals(Status.ACTIVE);
            boolean accountNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(Status.ACTIVE);
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(
                    Status.ACTIVE);
            boolean accountNonLocked = user.getStatus().equals(Status.ACTIVE);

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

            for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
            }

            // Spring Security Object
            // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User securityUser =
            // new User(
            // email, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
            // credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
            ActiveUser activeUser = new ActiveUser(user.getEmail(),
                    user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities,
                    user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(),
                    user.getImagePath());

            return activeUser;
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could exclude certain paths from scanning in SecurityConfiguration by setting 'excludeFilters' (excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(pattern = "com.beo*")') or setting concrete path for security config like '@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.beo.security" }'

Comment: I tried that. the userDetailsService is not getting injected.

Comment: where 'userDetailsService' is set?

Comment: com.beo.service.impl, i tried setting a concrete path, now it's giving me error about injecting of the userDAO. i'll post my userDetailsService class.